# Compiling sass with sourcemap

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there an easier way to compile my sass files with sourcemap enabled rather than the following command?

```
sass --compass --sourcemap --style compact --watch sass:css
```

If I was using compass, I would use 'compass watch' and it reads configurations from the config.rb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately.

In a future release Sass will emit the sourcemap as a default. https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1189

Until then, either a [grunt configuration](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#sourcemap) or an [alias in your bash profile](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) is your best bet.